# Regularization on indefinitely large training set?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have an indefinitely large training set to train a neural network.

Does it make any sense in this scenario to use regularization techniques like dropout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it probably still does.  Dropout is regularization in a sense, but much subtler than something like L1 norm.  It prevents excessive co-adaptation of feature detectors as described in the original paper.

You probably don't want the network to learn to depend on just one feature or just a small combo of features, even if that is the best feature in your training set, because it may not be the case in new data.  Intuitively, a network with dropout trained to recognize people in images will likely still recognize them if the face is obscured, even if there was no example image like that in the training set (because the face high level feature would have been dropped out some fraction of the time); a network trained without dropout may not (because the face feature is probably one of the best single features for detecting people).  You can think of dropout as a certain degree of forced concept generalization.

Empirically, the feature detectors that are produced with dropout are much more structured (eg, for images: closer to Gabor filters, for the first few layers) when dropout is used; without dropout they are closer to random (probably because that network approximates the Gabor filter it is converging towwards using a  specific linear combo of random filters, if it can rely on the elements of that combo not being dropped out then there is no gradient towards separating the filters).  This is also probably a good thing since it forces features which are independent to be implemented as independent early on, which may result in lower cross-talk later on.